# Finding Discord users with matching role criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, discord, discord.js

To begin, I have had zero experience with this kind of thing before starting this project. I have used various resources to get to the point of a fully functioning bot, but I am hung up on a key feature that I want to add.

What I'm trying to set up is a gaming matchmaking system for my Discord server. To do this users will opt into a timed "matchmaking" role which I already have set up and working.

What I want to do and am having trouble with is, I want to pull random users from that roll, that also have at least one matching role from two separate groups of "sub-roles" that represent "languages" (as in languages known for communication purposes" and "hardware" (as in what platform they will use for gaming).

I figure this would be done via an array/string or something similar and set up the following framework:

```
const english = message.guild.roles.get('671416995253714965');
const spanish = message.guild.roles.get('671417045916712961');
const french = message.guild.roles.get('671417095166361603');
const german = message.guild.roles.get('671417141731262516');
const japanese = message.guild.roles.get('671417224531279962');
const korean = message.guild.roles.get('671417269666185239');
const portuguese = message.guild.roles.get('671417316193599500');
const russian = message.guild.roles.get('671417467888730122');
const italian = message.guild.roles.get('671418325661777932');
const chinese = message.guild.roles.get('671418692742938647');

const pc = message.guild.roles.get('670715882292641812');
const mobile = message.guild.roles.get('670716301135839282');
const playstation = message.guild.roles.get('670716107929419789');
const xbox = message.guild.roles.get('670715986655313941');
const nintendo = message.guild.roles.get('670716141915602955');

let languages = ['english', 'spanish', 'french', 'german', 'japanese', 'korean', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'italian', 'chinese']
let hardware = ['pc', 'mobile', 'playstation', 'xbox', 'switch']
```

Edit: With Cipher's help, I now have a piece of code worked out that functions for an individual combination. I can use this format for each combination to create a monstrously long code that gives the desired result. I would still like to run through an array or something to clean up and simplify the code. Below is an example of the functioning code for one of the combinations.

V2: (d) is the "matchmaking" role

```
var myItaxbo = setInterval(() => {
    let itaxboList = message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.array().includes(d) && member.roles.array().includes(italian) && member.roles.array().includes(xbox));
    if(itaxboList.size > 1) {
    console.log(itaxboList.size)
    let randItaxbo = itaxboList.random(2)
    let firstItaxbo = randItaxbo[0]
    let secondItaxbo = randItaxbo[1]
    firstItaxbo.removeRole(d).catch(console.error);
    secondItaxbo.removeRole(d).catch(console.error);
    matchmakingChannel.send("Users <@" + firstItaxbo + "> and <@" + secondItaxbo + "> have been matched!")
    .then(msg => {
        msg.delete(3.6e+6)
    })
    } else {
        console.log('No itaxbo members')
        clearInterval(myItaxbo);
    };
    }, 5000);
```

V3

```
var mat = setInterval(() => {
    let membersList = message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.array().includes(d) && member.roles.some(role => languages.includes(role.id)) && member.roles.some(role => hardware.includes(role.id)));
    if (membersList.size > 1) {
    console.log(membersList.size)
    let randMembers = membersList.random(2)
    let firstMember = randMembers[0]
    let secondMember = randMembers[1]
    firstMember.removeRole(d).catch(console.error);
    secondMember.removeRole(d).catch(console.error);
    matchmakingChannel.send("Users <@" + firstMember + "> and <@" + secondMember + "> have been matched!")
    .then(msg => {
        msg.delete(3.6e+6)
    })
    } else {
        console.log('No members')
        clearInterval(mat);
    };
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Users can have more then 1 hardware and languages roles? If yes, so how need mathing them ?

Comment: Yes, they can have more than one of each. I wanted that for the languages in particular due to bilingual users. The hardware could be limited to one if necessary, but if I'm doing that process for one, I figure that I might as well do both.

Comment: Okay, rephrase a little;.

User has **pc** and **xbox** role, and has **english, spanish, french** roles.  So rand user can be `pc - english`, `pc-spanish` , `pc - french` , `xbox - english`, `xbox-spanish` and `xbox - french` right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I figured that an array of some kind would be easier than trying to making a map of some sort(like the "matchmaking" role) for each of those combinations and then finding common denominators from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do somethink like this. Filter GuildMembers, then check if they have game and languague  roles, and rand collection with get 2 rand members.

```js
    client.on('message', message => {
        const languages = ['english', 'spanish', 'french', 'german', 'japanese', 'korean', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'italian', 'chinese']
        const hardware = ['pc', 'mobile', 'playstation', 'xbox', 'nintendo']
        let membersList = guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.some(role => languages.includes(role.name)) && member.roles.some(role => hardware.includes(role.name)))
        if(membersList.size < 2) {
            console.log('No members')
            return
        }

        let randMembers = membersList.random(2)
        let firstMember = randMembers.first();
        let secondMeber = randMembers.last();

    });
```

**V2 version**

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  const languages = ['english', 'spanish', 'french', 'german', 'japanese', 'korean', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'italian', 'chinese']
  const hardware = ['pc', 'mobile', 'playstation', 'xbox', 'nintendo']
  let membersList = message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.some(role => languages.includes(role.name)) && member.roles.some(role => hardware.includes(role.name)))
  console.log(membersList.size)
  if(membersList.size < 2) {
      console.log('No members')
      return
  }

  let randMembers = membersList.random(2)
  let firstMember = randMembers[0]
  let secondMeber = randMembers[1]
});
```

**V3 Version** try get role by ID

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    const languages = ['123123', '12321312', '213213123'];
    const hardware = ['12321312', '213213213', '213213123'];
    let membersList = message.guild.members.filter(member => member.roles.some(role => languages.includes(role.id)) && member.roles.some(role => hardware.includes(role.id)));
    console.log(membersList.size);
    if (membersList.size < 2) {
        console.log('No members');
        return;
    }

    let randMembers = membersList.random(2);
    let firstMember = randMembers[0];
    let secondMeber = randMembers[1];
});
```

Comment: The code seems to only be returning "No members". I have myself and another user set to the appropriate roles that we should get matched, so that's not the problem. I tried changing the information in the arrays to some different formats and get the same thing. I tried replacing my original `const english = message.guild.roles.get('671416995253714965');` with this format `let english = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "english")` in case it was an issue reading role name vs. role id.

Comment: Changing ".size" to ".length" allows it to pass to the second part, but when I try to use the "firstMember" and "secondMember" they seem to return as "undefined". I tried running them through a channel message as "${firstMember}" and it posts exactly like that. When I tried to remove the "matchmaking" role from them as `firstMember.removeRole(roleID).catch(console.error);`, it returns "Cannot read property 'removeRole' of undefined"

Comment: I also had to change the bottom part because it returns "randMembers.first is not a function". I tried reformatting as this: `let firstMember = membersList.random();
    let secondMember = membersList.filter(m => m.user.id !== firstRand.user.id).random();`

Comment: Hmm, i will check it today and answer you whats went wrong. 
i use `size` because its a collection, collection has no length. 
Maybe some problem in members filter, can`t answer right now

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I just throw what little knowledge I have on this at the wall and see what sticks. lol

Comment: Hey, sorry for late answer, i find the problem. Missing message in filter....
V2 version code works fine :)

Comment: V2 returns "0" and "No members". I tried cutting the filter in half removing '`&& member.roles.some(role => hardware.includes(role.name))` to see if maybe it would at least match the single criteria, but it returned the same result.

Comment: I toyed with the code a bit and got it working on a single combination basis without the array of combinations. I added it to my original at the top. I still can't get it to run through the arrays though and would have to use that code repeatedly for each individual combination, which is bothersome and probably not very efficient.

Comment: Check your role names array

Comment: I had tried changing the `'english'` to `"english"`. I thought the code was having a problem with the former iteration due to it being the role ID. I figured switching to the later iteration would let it just match the term to the role name. But it returned the same result and thus I switched it back.

Comment: It is hard to say why this does not work in your case. I created several roles from your list on my server and issued them to several users. If I and the other user had a role from the first and second list, the code found us.

Comment: I edited my original post to show the entirety of my array and it's components, so you can see if there's something different there from what you have. When I try utilizing your code, the only thing I have to change is removing the `bot.on('message', message => {` due to this being ran as a command and initializing that way.

Comment: You need check it in interval without any message trigger ?

Comment: I put an interval on the above code because I wanted it to match as many users as possible from the available pool(which I didn't make clear before, but was a rather easy fix). Therefore I had it loop the code every few seconds until there weren't enough users to match anymore. I have this currently set up as a command on my discord bot that triggers with a "!!matching" command. I added the intervals in after getting that above code hammered out.

Comment: but i`ts always return zero users?

Comment: When I try your code with only the array and components of it listed above within my discord command. It returns only the 0 and "No members".

Comment: Check your role names, role.name must be === to role name in array. I check it again in my server and its work correctly.  Try this code to check if your role names in array names right. 

  `languages.forEach(langRole => console.log(message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === langRole)))`
  `hardware.forEach(hdRole => console.log(message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === hdRole)))`

Comment: Everything returns a "Null". I tried changing my formats to `const pc = message.guild.roles.get("name", "pc");`. I tried changing my array format to `const hardware = ["pc", "mobile", "playstation", "xbox", "nintendo"]`. I tried it as `const hardware = [pc, mobile, playstation, xbox, nintendo]`. I even tried copying and replacing me array with yours. Everything returns "Null". Yet my code without the array reads the components perfectly. If your components are formatted like mine above, I don't understand what it isn't working.

Comment: Hmmm, okay... Let do another way, try get role with ID, replace my fake role`s ID to some  your roles ID. I add it in **V3 version**

Comment: I converted the array to this `let languages = ['671416995253714965', '671417045916712961', '71417095166361603', '671417141731262516', '671417224531279962', '671417269666185239', '671417316193599500', '671417467888730122', '671418325661777932', '671418692742938647']
let hardware = ['670715882292641812', '670716301135839282', '670716107929419789', '670715986655313941', '670716141915602955']`. Everything still returns "Null". However, when I run the whole code, it gives me a number now.

Comment: I forgot to check and make sure that the test users had different roles. When separating 6 users (2 English/Mobile, 2 Chinese/PC, 2 Russian/Nintendo) it just matched them however such as 1 English/Mobile with 1 Russian/Nintendo.